# First derivative of this secial function

Tags: derivatives

What is the derivative of the following function:

$$f(x) = \frac{a}{((\sqrt{b+bx})(d-\sqrt{e+gx}))^2}$$

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) can tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Rewrite $$f(x) = \frac{a}{\Big((\sqrt{b+bx})(d-\sqrt{e+gx})\Big)^2}= \frac{a}{b(1+x)\Big((d-\sqrt{e+gx})\Big)^2}$$ $$f(x) = \frac{a}{b~~ u(x)~~ v(x)}=\frac{a}{b}\frac{1}{u(x)~ v(x)}$$ using $$u(x)=1+x$$ $$v(x)=w^2(x)$$ $$w(x)=d-\sqrt{e+gx}$$ which will make life simpler.  Now $$u'(x)=1$$ $$v'(x)=2w(x)~w'(x)$$ $$w'(x)=-\frac{g}{2 \sqrt{e+g x}}$$

I am sure that you can take from here and finish.